# Change the value of every row of the same column in MySQL in Python/Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a model like this in Django:

```
class Source_info(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    session_name = models.TextField()
    server_uname_path = models.TextField()
    server_name = models.TextField()
    server_fullpath = models.TextField()
    source_username = models.TextField()
    make_default = models.TextField()
```

I get make_default value as:

```
make_default = request.POST.get('make_default', True)
```

If user checks on make_default value is `'on'` otherwise it's `True`. One user can have only one make_default i.e. only one `'on'` per user. So I want to change previous value to `'True'` from on if the user checks on Make default. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think you should change the models.field into `make_default = models.BooleanField(default=True)`

Comment: most of your fields use `models.TextField()`, why?

Comment: Because too lazy to use CharField and use max_length.

Comment: Yes I am changed it to BooleanField. Still I want my case.

Comment: If user selects make_default now, the value will be 1. I want all the 1's transfer to 0 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def your_view(request, id):
    #change the current make_default into False
    default = SourceInfo.objects.get(user=request.user, make_default=True)
    default.make_default = False
    default.save()

    #the new make_default for user
    source = get_object_or_404(SourceInfo, pk=id)
    source.make_default = True
    source.save()

    .................
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand your question: each user can have at most one `Source_info` as their default. So when a user selects *this* `Source_info` as their default, you would like to deselect all the *other* ones for that user.

The reason you are having difficulty with this is that you have the model set up the wrong way round. If each user has at most one default `Source_info` then you need this to be a foreign key on the *user* model, not a flag on the `Source_info` model. So you should write instead:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # ... other fields ...
    default_source_info = models.ForeignKey('Source_info', null = True)
```

(If every user has *exactly* one default `Source_info` then you can omit the `null = True`.)

If the `User` model in question is the one from `django.contrib.auth`, then you should see the section "[Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)" in the Django documentation.

Comment: Yes, One user can only have one default make_default. There's no table called Source_info to do the foreign key. I want to delete the other defaults while the user checks the new one.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "There's no table called Source_info to do the foreign key"?

Comment: Where does Source_info come here? default_source_info = models.ForeignKey(Source_info, null = True)

Comment: `Source_info` is the name of your model class in your post above. Depending on which order you define the models in, you may need to quote it. I edited my answer to show how to do it.